# Removing multiple files from directory, as specified by variable in Makefile

Tags: linux, rm, makefile

I have a `Makefile` with the following configured for installing `man` pages

`MANDIR = /usr/share/man/man1`

`MANPAGES = exec1.1 exec2.1`

`make install` triggers the following:

`install: $(MANPAGES)
    install $(MANPAGES) $(MANDIR)`

I want to have a `make uninstall` which will undo this process.

Effectively, I need to do an `rm -rf $(MANDIR)/$(MANPAGE)` for each `man` page

Lots of ways I could probably do this, including loops, etc. Any quick tricks though for having `rm -rf` delete a list of files from a specified folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uninstall:
        rm -f $(addprefix $(MANDIR)/, $(MANPAGES))
.PHONY: uninstall
```

Note: make sure you use a [TAB] instead of eight spaces.

Comment: I'd forgotten about `addprefix` -- I don't work in `make` land often enough to remember those tricks. Thanks (and thanks for the `TAB` reminder).

Comment: @BSchlinker: if it works, would you please up-vote / mark accepted.  Thanks!